# Change the size of a file without opening the file

Tags: c#, file, size

With [`std::filesystem::resize_file`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/resize_file) in C++, it is possible to change the size of a file without opening the file.

Is there any similar function in C#, which allows changing the size of a file without opening it?

I think opening a file as a FileStream and saving it again with a new size will be slower.

Comment: How do you know `std::filesystem::resize_file` doesn't _"[open] the file"_?  The doco seems to [imply](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/resize_file) the POSIX `truncate` is used under the hood, which according to [this example](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/posix/truncate.c.html), _is_ opening the file.  Unless the FS supports sparse files?

Comment: @MickyD I don't think the standard C++ specifies the implementation of `resize_file`. So one cannot be sure how a compiler has implemented it. But it is faster for me and for sure it is possible to change the size of a file by changing specific bits in Hard Disk without opening the file.

Comment: [`std::filesystem::resize_file` source code](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libstdc++-v3/src/filesystem/std-ops.cc.html) shows that it calls `::truncate` which, according to one example at least, _does open the file_.  I'd suggest running _Sys Internals Process Monitor_ to know for sure. It could well be quicker at resizing than other operations but I'm not sure it does so _"without opening the file"_.  Perhaps you mean _"does not read file into memory"_ as mentioned by Matthew below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `FileStream.SetLength()` will be about as fast as you can make it.

It ends up calling the Windows API to set the length of the file, the same as the  `std::filesystem::resize_file()`.

So you just need to do something like this, and it will be fast enough:

```
using (var file = File.Open(myFilePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    file.SetLength(myRequiredFileSize);
}
```

The implementation of FileStream.SetLength() is:

```
    private void SetLengthCore(long value)
    {
        Contract.Assert(value >= 0, "value >= 0");
        long origPos = _pos;

        if (_exposedHandle)
            VerifyOSHandlePosition();
        if (_pos != value)
            SeekCore(value, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        if (!Win32Native.SetEndOfFile(_handle)) {
            int hr = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            if (hr==__Error.ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_FileLengthTooBig"));
            __Error.WinIOError(hr, String.Empty);
        }
        // Return file pointer to where it was before setting length
        if (origPos != value) {
            if (origPos < value)
                SeekCore(origPos, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            else
                SeekCore(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        }
    }
```

(Note that `SeekCore()` just calls the the Windows API `SetFilePointer()` function.)

Doing this does NOT read the file into memory.

Also, the Windows API function `SetEndOfFile()` does not write to the extended region, so it is fast. The documentation states `If the file is extended, the contents of the file between the old end of the file and the new end of the file are not defined.` - this is as a result of data not being written to the extended region.

As test, I tried the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace Demo
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string filename = @"e:\tmp\test.bin";
            File.WriteAllBytes(filename, new byte[0]); // Create empty file.

            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            using (var file = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
            {
                file.SetLength(1024*1024*1024);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
        }
    }
}
```

My E:\ drive is a hard drive, not an SSD.

The output was: `00:00:00.0003574`

So it took less than a hundreth of a second to extend the file to 1GB in size.

Comment: @MickyD Ah yes, I was trying to address the OP's underlying requirement rather than the thing they actually asked for. ;)